# Does using a laptop riser help make workplace more ergonomic?

Tags: health, ergonomics

I use a laptop (a 13-inch Macbook Pro) for my daily programming work. I've faced some back problems in the past, which I currently address through stretching exercises (via yoga).  Is there a way to modify my environment to improve the ergonomics of using a laptop all day?  Have laptop risers been found to help with this as claimed in [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5989633/five-best-laptop-stands)?

I understand a caveat that comes with the use of a laptop riser is that you have to use an external mouse.  How do the ergonomics of stand + external mouse compare to those of a plain laptop? It would be nice to hear what health benefits did you get by using a laptop with a riser. This will help me decide if it's really worth to get one(although I do understand it might not give me all the benefits that it might give another).

Comment: A riser may work for one person but not another. You need to find what works for **your** desk, **your** computer, and **your** body. There is no "one size fits all" answer here.

Comment: boddhisattva welcome to The Workplace.  I've made a fairly major edit to your question to focus it on something that we can answer rather than an opinion survey.  If I've misunderstood you please feel free to [edit] further.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about the kinds of questions we're looking for here.  Thanks.

Comment: Monica, Thanks for having me on this forum. I've edited the question a bit further. Hope it doesn't sound like an opinion survey with my edits. I shall go through the tour, thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: @alroc I understand where you're coming from. I've edited the question a bit. I'd like to know the benefits  if in case you've experienced any with the riser. It'll help me decide whether it's worth getting one or not. Thanks

Comment: You are using a 13" computer for programming? I hope you have an external keyboard and monitor plugged in? If not, I'd say that should be your first buy.

Comment: @Fredrik Valid point. I do have one such setup at office. I guess I might need to get one for home use  as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A riser will help your ergonomics if you can't otherwise position the display and keyboard in such a way that they are comfortable/proper.

The presence of the riser will not magically make your setup "more ergonomic." It's quite possible to have the wrong riser setup continue or even cause new/worse problems.

The only way to know for certain is to try it **with your work space**. If you have a plug-in keyboard, you can use a stack of books, reams of papers, or even cardboard boxes to change the positioning of your laptop display. Or get an external display and get that set up to the appropriate height/position.

Comment: the OP has a laptop not a workstation which is the problem laptops always have much worse ergonomics than a desk top its also not economically efficient to pay the premium for laptops if they spend 99% of the time on a desk.

Comment: Workstation meaning desk/cubicle/office space including chair.

Comment: @alroc - Thanks for pointing ways to try this. I see that even Jeanne(the other user who answered this question) uses a similar setup. It would be nice if you'd add more of your experience to your answer(it could probably just give me more pointers) as to what worked for you. I'd accept your answer as you brought up the point about using books first as a way of trying things out to start with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Laptops are poor for ergnomics. It's not possible to be at a good position for both keyboard/mouse and screen. This is why people often have to hunch down to use them. They are trying to properly position for keyboard/mouse. (Which I don't feel like I can achieve on a desk - I use a keyboard tray).

But presuming you do achieve a good position for keyboard/mouse, you are now way to low for your back/neck to look at the screen. A laptop riser alone can make the neck angle better. But then the laptop is to high for the keyboard/mouse. You should use an external keyboard and not just an external mouse.

At home, I have the following setup:

1. Keyboard tray with external keyboard and mouse. This is lower than the desk so a comfortable position to type.
2. My Mac laptop on top of a stack of three telephone books. (A telephone book is about the same thickness as a computer book.
3. An external monitor at the same height as the top of the laptop.

Comment: That's an interesting point that you brought up. I can try this with a set of books first and see if I find a difference and then this can help me decide whether getting a riser would be really helpful or not. Yep, we'd need an external keyboard too, it's my bad that I forgot mentioning it in the question. Thanks for the wonderful insights as to what's your current setup and what works for you, +1 .